# How to detect if the array is an space using loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, space

Hello guys Newbie here...
I try to accept an sentence then return it without vowels
By allocating nonvowels in new array but it seems it cant detect the value of arrays and it return undefine
I think the reason was when the character is space or special character.
but i try to detect spaces but did not work

```js
var array = "Your website is good";
var varray = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
var newarray = "";
for (let i = 0; i <= array.lenght; i++) {
  if (!(array[i].toLowerCase() == 'a' || array[i].toLowerCase() == 'e' || array[i].toLowerCase() ==
      'i' || array[i].toLowerCase() == 'o' || array[i].toLowerCase() == 'u')) {
    newarray = newarray + array[i];
    console.log(array);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide code that causes the error, the symbol or space, running the above code(with some changes as `length` has a typo) has no problems

Comment: You have a typo: `array.lenght` should be `array.length`

Comment: yeah it should be "length" my bad the loop work fine now thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

First, the variable called "array" is actually a string. Also, when declaring a new variable as an empty array, you would want to do:

```
var newArray = [];
```

So I think for this, you would want to separate the string into an array of lowercased words using

```
var wordsArray = array.toLowerCase().split(" ");
```

That will split the string into an array of lowercased words, without the spaces.

Then, you could loop through that array to separate each word into its own array of characters, something like:

```
for (let i = 0; i < wordsArray.length; i++) {
    let thisWordArray = wordsArray[i].split("");
    let thisArrayHolder = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < thisWordArray.length; i++) {
        if (!vowelsArray.includes(thisWordArray[j]) {
            thisArrayHolder.push(thisWordArray[j];
        }
        newArray.push(thisArrayHolder.join(""));
}
```

That will loop through each word, then during that loop, loop through each letter in the current word, check if that letter is a vowel (by seeing if it's in the vowelArray), then if it isn't, add it to the holder array. Then, at the end of that word, combine the letters of that holder array (which should now be an array of consonant-only letters) into a string, then add that whole string into the newArray. At the end of that, you'll have an array of words that don't have vowels. If you want to get that array back into string form, as a sentence of letters without vowels, you would need to do:

```
let newSentence = newArray.join(" ");
```

Comment: Hi, I don’t see the point of splitting the string at spaces. Could you explain?

Comment: Since `newArray` is empty, the `for` loop will never execute.

Comment: Because Mr.NewbieGoodie mentioned they thought the spaces were causing issues, I went ahead and did that. I don't think it's completely necessary, without seeing the rest of the code. Definitely possible my answer may not be the best or most concise/efficient.

Comment: Barmar, good catch - I forgot I had changed it. Edited to fix.

Comment: Thanks guys i follow your advice and replace value of empty string  "" into [] and it work s now it give good output. Thanks very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of simple mistakes:

1. `lenght` is a typo for `length`.
2. The loop condition should use `<` rather than `<=`. Array and string indexes go from `0` to `length-1`. That's the reason for the "undefined" error.
3. You have to log `newarray` rather than `array` to see the result. This is also only necessary at the end, not inside the loop.
4. You're not using the `varray` array.

```js
var array = "Your website is good";
var varray = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
var newarray = "";
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (!varray.includes(array[i].toLowerCase())) {
    newarray = newarray + array[i];
  }
}
console.log(newarray);
```

Your variable names are poorly chosen, since `array` and `newarray` are strings, not arrays.

Comment: Nice awesome It works thank you very much for the advice, my bad for the typo of length, nice I get it now the < and <= conditions so that why it's getting undefined value. Now it shows good results thanks its helpful.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems with the code in the question. The misspelling of 'length' has already been pointed out. You are also testing less than or equals so at the end of the array the code is trying to get a character that doesn't exist (remember, the counting started at zero).

With these two things sorted your code is OK, but it can be made shorter by for example using the JS function includes which will use your varray - testing whether the character at position i is contained in varray or not.

```js
var array = "Your website is good";
var varray = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
var newarray = "";
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  if (!varray.includes(array[i].toLowerCase())) {
    newarray = newarray + array[i];
  }
}
console.log(newarray);
```

Comment: Nice awesome thanks for the advice. And I will try it thanks for the helpful response.

Comment: and I think i will try search more build in function like include to shorten my future code thanks again.